# Accessing local json file in mobile storage using ajax request

Tags: html, cordova, apache-cordova

Can i access json file in a local storage of mobile using jquery.ajax or jquery.getJSON in Cordova.

Comment: Why do you want to access it using an ajax request? When it is on the same file system? why not just read it as a file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible! I just sugest you to access it from a .TXT file, not JSON. You just need to change the file extension. I say it because load a .JSON file can cause some problems for Windows Phone version.

**Look the code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    url: 'yourDirectory/JSONFile.txt',
    success: function (data) {
        var content = JSON.parse(data);

        doWhateverYouWant(content);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.